# YOLO neural network not compiling in VS13

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I'm trying to use [YOLO](http://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) in VS13, but it's not compiling. I was using [this](https://github.com/frischzenger/yolo-windows) (which gave me [this](https://github.com/frischzenger/yolo-windows/issues/1) error) and now I'm trying [this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/yolo-windows) (which is not compiling). If I use opencv 2.4.13, the error is

```
Error   1075    error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_core249.lib'
```

(downloading this lib not helping and causes another linker error)

If I use opencv 3.1.0 this error accures

```
Error   14  error : this declaration may not have extern "C" linkage    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\limits   78  1   darknet
```

I found [solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/darknet/opencv$203/darknet/AfZcD-C6yXY/RWp5V2tXBAAJ) which didn't work for me, because if i remove

```
#ifdef OPENCV
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
#endif
```

from image.h, and add it to image.c (generally it's already in image.c, so i'm just deleting this lines from image.h) the error accures in this lines (image.h)

```
#ifdef OPENCV
void save_image_jpg(image p, char *name);
image get_image_from_stream(CvCapture *cap);
image ipl_to_image(IplImage* src);
#endif
```

(CvCapture and IplImage not defined)

So, how can I use YOLO in windows? What should I fix in frischzenger or AlexeyAB solution?

Comment: stack overflow is not a support site for external tools. Any reason you don't ask the vendor of that library?

Comment: @Olaf this problem seems to be solved in listed links, but it's not working for me. So I'm asking if I did something wrong and maybe someone already faced same problem

Comment: Repeating what can be seen from your question is somewhat - useless.

Comment: I used https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet and its worked good. be carefull to define the libraries directory as described in the link

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of Yolo-Darknet on Windows 7/8/10/Server: v1(old) and v2(new).

1. Yolo v1: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/yolo-windows - can be compiled on **MSVS 2013**
2. Yolo v2 (since 17 Nov 2016): https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet - can be compiled on **MSVS 2015** or MSVS 2013 (12.0.40629.00 update 5), but not on MSVS 2013 (12.0.21005.1)

How to compile the current version Yolo v2 you can read there: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/yolo-windows#how-to-compile

About your question:

> I'm trying to use YOLO https://github.com/AlexeyAB/yolo-windows in VS13, but it's not compiling. I was using
>   this (which gave me this error) and now I'm trying this (which is not
>   compiling). If I use opencv 2.4.13, the error is
>
> Error   1075    error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_core249.lib'

1. In old Yolo v1, to using OpenCV 2.4.13 instead of 2.4.9 you should change such lines as `#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_core249.lib")` to `#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_core2413.lib")` in files:

   - `yolo_demo.c`
   - `yolo_kernels.cu`
2. In new Yolo v2, to using OpenCV 2.4.13 instead of 2.4.9 you should open file: `\src\yolo.c` and change 3 lines to your OpenCV-version - 249 (for 2.4.9), 2413 (for 2.4.13), ... :

   - `#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_core249.lib")`
   - `#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_imgproc249.lib")`
   - `#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_highgui249.lib")`

Use of Yolo v2 is preferable because higher speed and accuracy:
[image]